# Import data in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, import

i am working on a project with sql server database,after developing the project completed,i want to upload it to my website,so try to create my database on that website sql panel,so use the  Microsoft sql studio management an connect to my website database engine and import my local database to created database on my website.after import complete i checked the online database.all primary keys ,indexes and relationships delete!!!! i tried it again and again ,check all options,but i can not do that...

note : i want to import both my database structures and its data to an online database

thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use SSIS? What tools and scripts did you use?

Comment: Microsoft sql studio management 2008 R2 (use its import wizard)

Comment: Run SQL Profiler and trace all events. Do all databases attach to SQL Server?

Comment: yes,all attached,one of them attached to my local database engine , and other is on my website database engine

Comment: You must when set Column mappings->turn on "Append rows to the destination table" and turn of "Drop and re-create destination table"

Comment: you mean , first create my generation script of my local database , use it on my online database ,then import just data ?!! WOW , its great idea
thanks very much

Comment: @skorpk Please, add results of the discussion to your answer. Because, it does not look like an answer now.